# Angular: information if mobile or not in template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have many times this kind of code in my templates:

```html
<custom-button [align]="isMobile() ? 'center' : 'left'"></custom-button>
```

It requires as well to have a method in the component to know this so I have this method is almost all my components:

```js
  isMobile() {
    return Util.isMobile();
  }
```

This feels stupid to me but I didn't find any simple alternative. I know it feels like it could be just CSS but for this particular example, you can imagine that sometimes, it needs to be on the left, sometimes on the right, and you cannot control this by CSS because it's inside another component.

Can somebody give insights about how to manage this kind of issue?

Comment: Use boostrap 5: .justify-content-center .justify-content-md-start

Comment: What if I don't want to use bootstrap? (thx anyway)

Comment: Reinvent the wheel and create your own css styles that follows the same principles.

Comment: global css doesn't look like a good practice in the angular world or is it?

Comment: global css is not a good practice in angular, you are correct. The other downside of using css frameworks is the size of the css included and most likely unused. 

The approach most correct for this kind of issue is leveraging directives, most of the time in angular when you need to modify or structure dynamically the DOM you can use directives

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a directive, which you can add to your component. I have something similar using the `Angular Material CDK`.

Not sure if this applies to your specific needs, but this could be a good reference/starting point:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Util } from './path-to-util';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMobileAlign]'
})
export class MobileAlignDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const alignment = Util.isMobile() ? 'center' : 'left';

    //assuming this is for flex
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'justify-content', alignment);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do you use it in your component(s) ? (parent and child)

Comment: You can add a directive on your component in the template like so:
`custom-button appMobileAlign></custom-button>`. See https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives for more information.

Comment: is it ok to make a directive for each time I need something special depending on mobile/desktop ?? (I mean for example it may also be center / right, I would have 2 directives just for alignment)